# Event List start_date / end_date

Tags: php

I have an Event List which lists Events by start_date and end_date. What I want is to have the listing be dropped 4 days after the end_date. Can anyone help me with this? PS the site uses m/d/Y and the default time zone is set if that's of use in your reply. Thanks!

This is what was tried and it failed:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT events.* FROM events
LEFT JOIN eventsanctions ON eventsanctions.eventId = events.id
INNER JOIN sanctionbodies ON eventsanctions.sanctionId =sanctionbodies.id
AND eventsanctions.isPrimary =1 and   events.status=1 order by         events.race_date asc";
                        if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            //echo "<pre>";
                            //print_r($row);
                            */$newdate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime( '+4    day' , strtotime ( $row['end_date'] ) ));
                            if(strtotime($today) < strtotime($newdate))/*
                            {                               
                            ?>
```

I thought this might work but I assume I need my start_date and end_date inserted properly:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$start = date('m/d/Y');
$end = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+4 days'));

while (strtotime($start) <= strtotime($end)) {
echo "$start\n";
$date = date ("m/d/Y", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start)));
}
?>
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: This website is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (strtotime($start) <= strtotime($end)) {
echo "$start\n";
$date = date ("m/d/Y", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start)));
}
```

Looks like you're trying to loop through each day, but `$date` is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I offened anyone but without much help here I decided to go with a Cron job.